# Avoid Windows Login Prompt While Accessing Report Server

Tags: security, reporting-services

We are using Microsoft Reporting Service 2008 R2 to develop reports and we are accessing these reports through an ASP application.

`Response.Redirect(http://<serverIp>:80/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fReport+Project3%2fReport1&rs:Command=Render&quotn_Id=675);`

When I access my report-server through my web service URL, it prompted for a windows login and password when accessed from a different machine (working fine if I provide the Credentials), but it is working fine in the local machine.
What configuration do I need to adopt to get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to change the authentication type to Windows authentication (`Integrated Security`) in the `SSRS Config/IIS Manager`:

- Open IIS Manager.
- Right-click the report server virtual directory and click Properties.
- Click Directory Security.
- In Authentication and access control, click Edit to open the Authentication Methods dialog box.
- (Optional) Clear the Integrated Windows authentication check box.
- If the report server virtual directory is configured for both Integrated Windows authentication and Basic authentication, the report server will try Windows authentication first. If you want to use only Basic authentication, you must clear the Integrated Windows authentication check box.
- Select Basic authentication.
- Set the default domain or realm used to authenticate clients to the Web server.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283249(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Thanks dude..this Links leads to Configuration of sql server 2005 if i go to  Service 2008 R2 it shows other methods by editing  RSeportServer.config file  (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281253(v=sql.105).aspx) when i edited as per but now the output is not coming even in my system