# How to remove SSRS Report Manager URL login screen

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to migrate several SSRS reports from a client's old SQL Server 2008 R2 on Windows Server 2003 R2 to a new SQL Server 2012 on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have it all set up except that on the new system, when I click on the Report Manager URL from within Reporting Services Configuration Manager, it pops up a login screen.  The old system looks identical, but it does not pop up the login screen.

I have tried checking the "remember my credentials" but with no effect.

I have entered this login in the Site Settings -> Security screen and in the Folder Settings -> Security screen with no effect.

The client has the requirement that they never see the login screen.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me to a solution?

Thanks,
dtaylor

Comment: have a look at this [`Avoid Windows Login Prompt While Accessing Report Server`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10796195/avoid-windows-login-prompt-while-accessing-report-server)

Comment: M.Ali, thanks for the reply.  However, I have already been to that page and implemented the solution with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out and will post here for completeness.
In my case it wasn't the way SSRS was configured at all.  I noticed that the login page was for the computer credentials and not database credentials.  I further noticed that the ONLY difference between the account on the old server and the account on the new server was that the old server account was just a standard user account but the account I was using on the new server was the built-in Administrator account.  At first I dismissed this, but just for grins, I created another user account on the new server and logged back into the server with the new account.  Et Voila, I can now link to the reports without incurring a login page.